# Windows 10 Bluetooth disappears until power down

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bluetooth, sleep, alien

I have seen a lot of posts/threads related to windows and Bluetooth "disappearing". Most seemed to be resolved with reboots/service changes/etc. I think my issue may be different but I'm not sure how best to troubleshoot this.

I know this is about my Bluetooth but there are a couple of other issues that may be related or indicate a bigger problem?

1. Randomly the Bluetooth will stop working and disappear from the device manager sometimes it will be days between this happening, other times its happened within the same hour. I can reboot windows multiple times and it will not come back until I power down the machine.
2. Frequently fails to sleep. I will close the lid, the lights on the laptop stay on. When I open the laptop back up the keyboard lights and even the screen back light come on but the screen is black. Until I push the power button which seems to send it to hibernate. then push the power button again and it will resume.
3. Sometimes when I wake it up i will have a blank screen that reads "no bootable device" in the top left of the screen. When I hold the power button and restart the laptop it boots fine.
4. Audio will stop working randomly. Similar to Bluetooth but it does come back after a reboot and doesn't require a full shut down. Unlike other times ive had audio issues this one doesn't "red x" the volume speaker and windows seems to think there is an audio device to play to, just no sound comes out.
5. Fans randomly go to full speed. Trivial maybe, expected maybe im not sure. Computer will stutter/freeze for a few seconds and the fans will kick in full speed. In conjunction with this I some times also see an error that alien ware tacx has had a hardware fault.

Steps so far.

1. I don't remember the exact command but, pwrconfig said my sound blaster card prevented sleep. Read a lot of stuff about creatives driver extras from dell so I uninstalled those. Haven't checked pwrconfig again yet.
2. Reinstalled the os. I originally noticed these things happening while running the laptop with the factory image from dell (laptop is only a little over a month old). I thought maybe installing a clean copy of windows (i have an msdn licence) and installing the drivers directly would clear the problems up. It hasn't.
3. Turned off hybrid sleep. No change

Should include some computer details maybe? I understand most of the hardware shouldn't matter. The sound card and wireless card may be an issue though, or common driver issue.

Alienware 17 r3

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HK (Q uad-Core, 8MB Cache, Dynamical ly Overclocked up to 4.1GHz)

32GB Dual Channel DDR4 2133Mhz (16GBx2)

Killer 1535 802.11ac 2x2 WiFi and Bluetooth 4.1

Sound Blaster Recon3Di (I cant find anything more specific)

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm having a very similar issue - disappears and reappears.

Comment: A new network card fixed it.